# Is there different when you format number as quantity and number as currency?

Tags: localization, formatting, currency

Is there a difference when formatting a number used as quantity vs formatting a number used as currency.

In other words - does l10n on currency only define the currency sign position or there might be formatting to the actual number too?

Example (assuming we use same locale):

Are those possible (meaning thousand 2hundred 34 in all cases):

1. "I have 1 234 apples and I paid 1,234 EUR for them."
2. "I have 1.234 apples and I paid 1,234 EUR for them."

Or number will always be the same format given same locale?

Example:

1 234 apples  /  1 234 EUR

1.234 apples  /  1.234 EUR

1,234 apples  /  1,234 EUR

Comment: What do you mean "formatting on the actual number too?" Like `1234` in some locale might be expressed with different digits?

Comment: Currency format tends to follow number format; it is *possible* that exceptions exist, but they would be rather rare.

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL: Let's take the number 10234.56 (ten thousand, two hundred and thirty three, and fifty six hundredths). Americans would write `10,234.56`, most Europeans `10 234,56`; IIRC, an Indian might write this as `1 0234.56`. The value remains the same, the digits are the same (except for the countries using Eastern Arabic numerals); decimal separators, digit separators and their positions aren't (hence the [localization] tag). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thousands_separator#Digit_grouping

Comment: Yes I know based on locale number format varies. But does it vary also when you refer to it in different context for example (quantity vs currency)

Answer (score 0):

Localized formatting of amounts of money has several aspects, including the currency name or symbol, or code (e.g., euro ~ евро; codes like EUR are not intended for normal text), its placement as relative to the number, spacing or other separator between them, and also the formatting of the number. Of course, the currency itself may need to be localized, but that’s a different issue.

In general, formatting of numbers in this context should be regarded as distinct from normal formatting of numbers. Quite often, there is no difference, but there may be (e.g., different grouping of digits).

Comment: Ok, so you're saying context (amount vs money) matters. Can you point out a document to backup your thoughts or perhaps some real example.

Comment: I intended to include a reference to http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Number_Elements but forgot, thanks for reminder. The document describes the elements for numbers in CLDR, with separate definitions for numeric formats in currency context.